# Any quicker way than pandas fillna()?

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

`Pandas` `fillna()` is significantly slow especially if there is a big amount of missing data in a dataframe.

Is there any quicker way than it?

(I know that it would help if I simply dropped some of the rows and/or columns that contain the NAs)

Comment: @jezrael, for all missing data of a dataframe (i.e. all rows & columns).

Comment: @jezrael, all columns are categorical (ordinal not one-hot-encoded). Number of rows is 60k and of columns is 20. The percentage of missing values is high (30%).

Comment: @jezrael, yes ;) and the missing values are `None`.

Comment: @jezrael, any ideas or you quit? :) (if you quit then probably nobody will have sth better to say so I may delete my post haha)

Comment: @jezrael, ok so you mean that you tested it something different but it had about the same performance as `fillna`? (Sorry I did not understand what you meant exactly at your last message)

Comment: exactly, you are right

Comment: @jezrael, ok I see. Good to know then, thanks for now! ;)

Comment: @QuangHoang, you could post your answer if you want to below (with some time profiling too perhaps).

Comment: @jezrael, how come you did not come up with what Quang Hoang says? :)

Comment: My test `%timeit df.fillna(0)
94.4 ms ± 1.28 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit df[df.isna()] = 0
121 ms ± 665 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`

Comment: Sample data for test `np.random.seed(123)
N = 60000
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(['a', None], size=(N, 20), p=(.7, .3)))`

Comment: Never mind what I said. Second test showed similar result with @jezrael's. My computer must have been doing something crazy.

Comment: @QuangHoang - I find someting similar like your answer - it seems fastest

Comment: Answer is edited with a bit changed solution with `df.values[df.isna()] = 'b'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I try to test:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 60000
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(['a', None], size=(N, 20), p=(.7, .3)))
```

---

```
In [333]: %timeit df.fillna('b')
93.5 ms ± 1.28 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [337]: %timeit df[df.isna()] = 'b'
122 ms ± 2.75 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

A bit changed solution (but I feel it is a bit hacky):

```
#pandas below
In [335]: %timeit df.values[df.isna()] = 'b'
56.7 ms ± 799 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

#pandas 0.24+
In [339]: %timeit df.to_numpy()[df.isna()] = 'b'
56.5 ms ± 951 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Cool so regarding `df.fillna('b')` and `df[df.isna()] = 'b'`, then the former is much faster? I thought that you were saying that the opposite was true. (In any case, it is fine with me; I am just asking to be clear).

Comment: @Poete Maudit If check answer of use `df[df.isna()] = 'b'` it is slowier like `fillna`, faster is if asssign to numpy array `df.values[df.isna()] = 'b'`